# Enviar array JavaScript via Ajax com jQuery para arquivo PHP

Tags: javascript

Quero enviar um array via jQuery usando Ajax para um outro arquivo PHP, porém não sei como acessá-lo no PHP.
Estou enviando por `GET` não sei se seria o ideal também.

`nome_receita` é uma variável e `ingredientes` é a array que preciso "abrir" no PHP.

```js
$.get("http://localhost/estudos/oquetemprahj/servidor.php?nome_receita="+nome_receita+"&&ingredientes="+ingredientes+"",function(retorno)
{
 alert(retorno);
});
```

Comment: Use console.log(retorno); e veja a saída no console do navegador, para capturar no php vai depender do tipo de requisição, no seu caso vc está usando $.get(), o get é capturado por `$_GET['nome_receita']`. se deseja exibir o retorno, você precisa dar um "echo" no que foi enviado.

Comment: O ideal é que você utilize o método POST, e tenha este retorno em json. O método get é recomendado para requisição relativamente rápidas, e que necessitam preservar variáveis na url.

Comment: Não dá para enviar um array em javascript via get, não é assim que funciona, vc tem que converter esse array antes de enviar, usando serialize / unserialize, ou enviar a estrutura do objeto json via POST. Ou converter essa variável em string: `JSON.stringify(ingredientes)`

Answer (score 1):

Basta adicionar [] após o nome da variável.
Exemplo:

```
$.get("http://localhost/estudos/oquetemprahj/servidor.php?nome_receita="+nome_receita+"&ingredientes[]=item1&ingredientes[]=item2&ingredientes[]=item3",function(retorno)
{
    alert(retorno);
});
```

Basta substituir item pelo valor da chave. No PHP chegará como Array, você pode fazer o teste:

```
print_r($_REQUEST["ingredientes"]);
```

Se for um checkbox, por exemplo, você pode fazer o seguinte:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="ingrediente_x" name="ingredientes[]">
<input type="checkbox" value="ingrediente_y" name="ingredientes[]">
<input type="checkbox" value="ingrediente_z" name="ingredientes[]">
```

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que para este tipo de cenário um `POST` seja mais apropriado, neste caso tente fazer o seguinte.:

```
var data = {
    nome_receita: nome_receita, 
    ingredientes: ingredientes
};

var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
httpRequest.open("POST", "http://localhost/estudos/oquetemprahj/servidor.php", true);
httpRequest.responseType = "json";
httpRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
httpRequest.send(JSON.stringify(data));
```

caso queira testar o envio por `GET`, basta substituir o `POST` por `GET` no `open(...)`.

com `jQuery` você pode tentar o seguinte:

```
var data = {
    nome_receita: nome_receita, 
    ingredientes: ingredientes
};

$.get("http://localhost/estudos/oquetemprahj/servidor.php", data, function(retorno)
{
    alert(retorno);
});
```

Comment: Certo entendi, mas como acessaria essas informações no PHP?

Comment: @EliezerB. à sua duvida é de como enviar os dados e não como o PHP vai receber e responder a requisição.

Answer (score 0):

No script PHP que receberá os dados, basta você acessar usando $_GET, ou $_POST, se o método for post. Então ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
<?php
    $nome_receita = $_GET['nome_receita'];
    $ingredientes = json_decode($_GET['ingredientes']);
?>
```

Acredito que como **ingredientes** se trata de um array, você tenha que usar a função json_decode() do PHP.

Também é importante ressaltar que você usou o **&** duas vezes para a variável ingredientes, na passagem da URL.

Answer (score 0):

Creio que você pode usar a função $.ajax do jQuery, mas antes você precisa transformar o seu array em uma string JSON. Um bom jeito é usando o JSON.stringify. [Link para a documentação do JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

Código para fazer a chamada ajax:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://localhost/estudos/oquetemprahj/servidor.php',
  type: 'GET', // Tipo de requisição, podendo alterar para GET, POST, PUT , DELETE e outros metodos http
  data: {nomeReceita: nome_receita, ingredientes: ingredientes},
  success: function(resposta){
     //Bloco com a resposta do servidor caso a requisição ocorra normalmente
  },
  error: function(resposta){
    //Entrará aqui caso não de certo a requisição 
  }
})
```

Já no seu php você vai ter que pegar esses dados e passar e passar eles de string JSON para objeto.

```
<?php

$nome_receita = $_GET['nome_receita'];
$ingredientes = json_decode($_GET['ingredientes']);
```